# Proving a statement about graph complements

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph and $x$ a vertex in G
Is it true that $\overline{G-x}\cong\overline G-x$?

I know that self complementary means that an order of n graph n is a multiple of 4 or the remainder on dividing equals 4...How does being self-complementary make a difference to the question
For example if G=11 and took away a vertice the graph wouldn't be self-complementary anymore so is the equation not true anymore?

Comment: No, self-complementary means that $\overline G$ is isomorphic to $G$. Your question has nothing to do with self-complementarity, it's true for any graph $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be a graph, and let $G^c$ be the complement graph of $G.$ By definition, the vertices of $G^c$ are the same as the vertices of $G,$ and a pair $(v, w)$ of vertices of $G$ is an edge of $G$ if and only if $(v, w)$ is not an edge of $G^c.$ If $x$ is a vertex of $G,$ then $x$ is not a vertex of $G - x$ or $G^c - x,$ hence $x$ is not a vertex of $(G - x)^c,$ and there are trivially no edges in either $(G - x)^c$ or $G^c - x$ that are incident to $x.$ We can therefore restrict our attention to the edges $(v, w)$ of $G^c$ such that neither $v$ nor $w$ is $x.$ Explicitly, $(v, w)$ is an edge of $G^c - x$ if and only if $(v, w)$ is an edge of $G^c$ and $x \notin \{v, w\}$ if and only if $(v, w)$ is not an edge of $G$ and $x \notin \{v, w\}$ if and only if $(v, w)$ is not an edge of $G - x$ if and only if $(v, w)$ is an edge of $(G - x)^c,$ so we have equality $(G - x)^c = G^c - x.$